# Solution of a differential equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I did my own study and research and currently know the solution to the equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c$ is $f(x) = f(0) + cx$, where $c$ is a constant. However, I am struggling with finding solution to: 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=c\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$

I ultimately want to find the following integral:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

in terms of $g$, $a$ and $b$. Thanks.

An example would be really appreciated. What the solution look like when, for example, $g(x)=1-cosh(x)$.

Comment: Since you know nothing about $g(x)$ you won´t get a specific solution.

Comment: @callculus The OP specified that it could be in terms of $g$.

Comment: @callculus Yes, wondering what is the general solution and how to approach it.

Comment: @AlexKim Your answer will also have to be in terms of the constant of integration that you get when you integrate both sides.

Comment: @AlexKim Have a look to Nilknarfs answer. It looks that this is what you wanted.

Comment: @AlexKim Has my answer helped you? If so, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what your constant of integration is.

By integrating both sides with respect to $x$,
$$f(x)=c\int g'(x)dx$$
$$f(x)=cg(x)+C$$
and so
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b(cg(x)+C)dx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=c\int_a^b g(x)dx+\int_a^b Cdx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=c\int_a^b g(x)dx+C(b-a)$$
And so the answer must *also* be in terms of the constant of integration $C$.

Comment: How to obtain the constant. Is it: C=f(0)-cg(0)? I know g(0) but I do not know f(0)?